# WSO2 - SCIM request not produced when creating a new object on LDAP

Tags: ldap, wso2, scim, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server 5.10.0 with an Open LDAP as a user store and I want to send a SCIM request to another server whenever a new user is created.

To do that I configured my WSO2 to do Outbound Provisioning, by following the WSO2 documentation.

When I create a new user through the Management Console, a SCIM request is properly sent, which tells me that my Outbound Provisioning configurations are probably correct.

However, when I create a new user by constructing a new object directly on the LDAP, no SCIM request is sent to the other server even though the user is properly created and appears when you go to "List" under "Users and Roles" in WSO2's Management Console.

What could be the cause of this and what can I do about it?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the expected behavior and it's correct.

When you directly create users in the LDAP, WSO2 is not aware of those user creation events. Since the outbound provisioning is triggered upon a successful user creation event, your observation is expected.

Creating users directly in the LDAP is not recommended. User identities should be managed via WSO2 Identity Server. Otherwise, there could occur more issues (caching and data inconsistency issues) than just a provisioning failure.

Finally, if you want WSO2 to provision the users automatically you should create the users via WSO2 (SCIM or management console). Otherwise, you might have to delegate the outbound provisioning process to whatever the entity that's creating users in the LDAP directly.

Comment: Is this also the case if we add the users directly in the WSO2 embedded LDAP? Is there no way for an add operation there to initiate a SCIM request as well?

Comment: Yes, despite being embedded or not, direct actions against LDAP server will not trigger WSO2 provisioning flows. If you want them to trigger, you have to add via WSO2 server.